# ServletFileUpload.parseRequest() wants RequestContext instead of HttpServletRequest request

Tags: java, servlets

i am writing a web app and i want to upload a file to the servlet.
i read that i can use ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(request)
it works on one computer.
but when i try to run the code on another computer i get an error that the function needs  RequestContext: ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(RequestContext)

on the computer that the function works with HttpServletRequest i see the function with RequestContext. but i don't use it

is there another way to upload files to servlet?

Comment: Can you post the code? Are you sure you are passing in an HttpServletRequest? Are you sure you are using the same commons-fileupload library on both machines?

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
new ServletFileUpload().parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(request));
```

This change works on the latest apache tomcat (at least on 7.0.70, which I am using).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a container (eg Tomcat 7+) that implements Servlet 3.0? That version of the spec has been around for a few years, and has added an API for uploading files.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glrbb.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both environment have the same Apache fileupload jar.  I'm using commons-fileupload-1.2.2 and it have both methods

ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(HttpServletRequest request) and ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(RequestContext context)

Comment: How do i do I do that? how can I change the jar?

Comment: All the dependent jars are located in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your web project